# Update failed. Reason: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'deltagenerator' cannot be converted to a MySQL type. Not sure how to fix the error

Tags: python, mysql, streamlit

Edit function

```
def edit_details(new_typeofcard, card_no):
    c.execute("UPDATE card_type SET typeofcard=%s, card_no=%s WHERE "
              "card_no=%s", (new_typeofcard, card_no))
    mydb.commit()
    data = c.fetchall()
    return data
```

It's being referenced here and not sure where the error's coming from.

```
def update():
    result = view_all_data()
    df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['Card Type','Card Number'])
    with st.expander("Current entries"):
        st.dataframe(df)


    list_of_users = [i[0] for i in view_only_id()]
    selected_user = st.selectbox("Entries to Edit", list_of_users)
    selected_result = get_details(selected_user)
    
    if selected_result:
        typeofcard = selected_result[0][0]
        card_no = selected_result[0][1]


        col1, col2 = st.columns(2)
        with col1:
            new_typeofcard = st.text_input("Enter type:", typeofcard)
        with col2:
            card_no = st.text_input("Card Number:", card_no)

        if st.button("Update"):
            try:
                edit_details(new_typeofcard, card_no)
                st.success("Successfully updated")
            except Exception as e:
                st.error("Update failed. Reason: {}".format(e))


    result2 = view_all_data()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(result2, columns=['Card Type', 'Card Number'])
    with st.expander("Updated data"):
        st.dataframe(df2)
```

I tried executing the edit function and it kept giving the same error. Not sure how to tackle it.

Comment: At least one of `new_typeofcard` and `card_no` is a type of object (`deltagenerator`) that can't be passed directly to MySQL.  Print the `type()` of each and then replace with a sensible type (usually a string or  numeric type).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure where to make the changes could you edit the code and show me where?